# Insert multiple records in SQL where values are all combinations of defined ranges in single query

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, where-in

How to write  sql query

I need something like

```
Insert Into database.table (userID,credID,time) 
values 
userId = for all in (10,15,12,17,14,267,16,689,18,7659,20)
credID = for all in (1,2,3,4,5) 
time = constant (forall the same)
```

now database structure

userID,credID,time
10,34,2013-12-12
10,54,2013-12-12

so i must get

```
userID,credID,time
10,34,2013-12-12
10,54,2013-12-12
10,1,2013-12-12
10,2,2013-12-12
10,3,2013-12-12
10,4,2013-12-12
10,5,2013-12-12
11,1,2013-12-12
11,2,2013-12-12
11,3,2013-12-12
11,4,2013-12-12
11,5,2013-12-12
....
```

for logical algoritm must be like

for each userID in range (10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)
insert new fields with credID values (1,2,3,4,5)

For single userID i can create single credID with query 
`insert into database.table (userID,credID,time) values (10,1,2013-12-12)` 
but i need to insert multiple credID for multiple userID

Comment: your sql pseudocode was little confusing, I edited it - is this what you mean?

Comment: maybe. credID is new parametr not in table. userId always is in table with others credID

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by *"userId always is in table with others credID"*

Comment: userId constantly present in the database with other credID, i need insert new credID for existing userID

Comment: 1) for all of them or only for some? 2) these userIDs are all part of database.table?

Comment: for all wich in comma separated list

Comment: userID are all part of database.table yes

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:

```
INSERT INTO table1( userID,credID,time)
SELECT x,y,'2013-12-12' 
FROM (
  SELECT 1 As x union
  SELECT 2 union
  SELECT 3 union
  SELECT 4 union
  SELECT 5
) xx
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT 10 As y union
  SELECT 11 union
  SELECT 12 union
  SELECT 13 union
  SELECT 15 union
  SELECT 16 union
  SELECT 17 union
  SELECT 18 union
  SELECT 19 union
  SELECT 20
) yy
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8398d/1

---

EDIT.
If these two lists of numbers are dense, there is another trick with table of numbers:

```
CREATE TABLE numbers( x int primary key auto_increment );

INSERT INTO numbers
SELECT null FROM information_schema.columns
LIMIT 100;

CREATE TABLE   table2
  (userID int,credID int,time date);

INSERT INTO table2( userID,credID,time)
SELECT n1.x,n2.x,'2013-12-12' 
FROM numbers n1
CROSS JOIN numbers n2
WHERE n1.x BETWEEN 1 AND 5
  AND n2.x BETWEEN 10 AND 20
;
```

demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e121d/1

---

EDIT.
There is an another trick with the table of numbers.
If you want to pass these two lists as comma separated strings, then try this query:

```
CREATE TABLE numbers( x int primary key auto_increment );

INSERT INTO numbers
SELECT null FROM information_schema.columns
LIMIT 100;

CREATE TABLE   table1
  (userID int,credID int,time date);

INSERT INTO table1( userID,credID,time)
SELECT xx,yy,'2013-12-12' 
FROM (
        SELECT reverse( if( locate(',',reverse(SUBSTRING_INDEX( y, ',', x ))) > 0,
                          substr( reverse(SUBSTRING_INDEX( y, ',', x )), 1, locate(',',reverse(SUBSTRING_INDEX( y, ',', x ))) -1 ),
                          reverse(SUBSTRING_INDEX( y, ',', x ))
                     )) AS xx
        FROM (  select '1,22,333,44,51,656'  y ) q
        JOIN numbers n
        ON n.x <= length( y ) - length( replace( y, ',','')) + 1
) q1
CROSS JOIN
(
        SELECT reverse( if( locate(',',reverse(SUBSTRING_INDEX( y, ',', x ))) > 0,
                          substr( reverse(SUBSTRING_INDEX( y, ',', x )), 1, locate(',',reverse(SUBSTRING_INDEX( y, ',', x ))) -1 ),
                          reverse(SUBSTRING_INDEX( y, ',', x ))
                     )) AS yy
        FROM (  select '111,222,3333,444,54,656'  y ) q
        JOIN numbers n
        ON n.x <= length( y ) - length( replace( y, ',','')) + 1
) q2
;
```

Demo --> http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/83c86/1

Comment: wow, nice extension for my solution :-) Nice trick. You need however another language to generate the code dynamically

Comment: @Tomas Yes, you are absolutely right, these two list must be created somehow, either dynamicaly or someone must enter numbers manually.

Comment: Maybe you could do it somehow in the procedural part of SQL itself (which is used for programming procedures etc) :-) But that would probably not be the standard SQL

Comment: +1 for the first approach :-) I think its probably necesary for the OP solution. The second one is a nice trick too but too complicated already

Comment: @Tomas I've added another solution, give it a try

Comment: OMG.. you are founder of anti-[KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) principle, aren't you :)

Comment: @Tomas yes you are absolutely right! Unfortunately MySql is horribly limited, things that needs a few line of SQL in other databases like PostgreSQL, Oracle etc., in MySql require monsters like this query.

Comment: kordiko, interesting - you think this would be much easier in PostgreSQL?

Comment: @Tomas, if you don't belive, please take a look at simple demo for PostgreSQL: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d0ff6/2

Comment: kordiko, WOW! One reason more to migrate to PostgreSQL (the other two I heard about is scalability(?) and PostGIS)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in SQL *in general*, unless those value ranges are part of some other table. In that case, you can do it by joining the ranges without any joining key - that will produce the desired cartesian product:

```
insert into database.table (userID,credID,time)
select userID, credID, '2011-12-12'
from (select userID
      from database.table
      where userID in (10,15,12,17,14,267,16,689,18,7659,20))
  join (select credID 
        from database.table
        where credID in (54, 34, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
```

But as I said above - in this code we assume that the `database.table` contains all listed userIDs and all credIDs 1..5. But that's not necessarily a hinderance - on the contrary, **in most practical situations you need to assure that those values exist** - not necessarily in the table you insert into, but usually in another table in the database (then you have to modify the subqueries accordingly).

However if for example the credID are *new* as you said and not contained in any table yet, you have to use approach of @kordiko (credit to him) and combine it in the query above:

```
insert into database.table (userID,credID,time)
select userID, credID, '2011-12-12'
from (select userID
      from database.table
      where userID in (10,15,12,17,14,267,16,689,18,7659,20)) as t1
  join (select 34 as credID union 
        select 54 union
        select 1 union
        select 2 union
        select 3 union
        select 4 union
        select 5
        ) as t2
```

Comment: userID cant be between it must be different 10,52,98,75454,564

Comment: @user3146584 I don't understand what you mean by *"it must be different 10,52,98,75454,564"*. But you want userIDs that are already part of the database.table? But which one of them? Can you write an SQL query that selects those userIDs from database.table?

Comment: select userID from database.table where userID=1

Comment: @user3146584 you can use condition like `userID in (10,52,98,75454,564)`. See my edit. Is this what you want?

Comment: For single userID i can create single credID with query
insert into database.table (userID,credID,time) values (10,1,2013-12-12)
but i need to insert multiple credID for multiple userID

Comment: userID and credID cant be between

Comment: @user3146584 doesn't have to, you may do the same as for userID

Comment: But credID is a new value not existing for user wich is in range

Comment: @user3146584 I know, look at the second query!